# sybase tempdb log segment filling

Tags: sap-ase, tempdb

I have a Sybase ASE server that hangs every week or so, indicating `tempdb` log segment is full.

I have tried everything. `trunc log on chkpt` is enabled and it works correctly resetting `used_pages` about every 60 seconds or so.

The problem is, not all the pages freed are returned to `free_pages`. So, over time, `free_pages` eventually ends up at 0, while `used_pages` is minimal. The values I'm referring to come from the query `sp_spaceused syslogs` on `tempdb`. It's like a memory leak!

Currently when I run this command I get:

```
total_pages: 64000 
free_pages: 29719
used_pages: 251
reserved_pages: 0
```

Every time I run the command, `used_pages` increases which is also odd.

This database is running on 64-bit Windows Server 2003. I have another similarly configured ASE server that does not have these issues. The contents of this other database are similar. This database is running on 32-bit Windows Server 2003. There's no need to move `tempdb` to a different device or expand its size any further because this other server operates perfectly and it is configured the same as the one that has odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on application that running on this ASE.
Try to monitor application with ASE monitoring tables.

Look at very advanced presentation http://download.sybase.com/presentation/TW2005/ASE115.pdf.